# Scrapy a link with a protection?

Tags: scrapy

I want to scrapy the link between this protection ?

```
https://dl-protect.xyz/1pf7uwq3
```

Someone can tell me if really possible to do this ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can obtain the download link, then yes. I won't actually try to download this file but the "continue" button has a token and callback to a function JS called "onSubmit()". This function the I ASSUME takes you to the download page.

You should always include what you are trying to accomplish when posting on here; also writing elaborate well thought out question is key to getting the response your looking for!

> Someone can tell me if really possible to do this ?

I scrapy shelled the site with no user-agents and got a 200 response so seems like there should be no reason why you would not be able to "scrapy" the site.

Comment: ty a lot but i'm new to scrapy and i test to do this since 20 hours now :( and no success... and when english is not your 1st language it's very hard to have long sentence and explanation... for me
but it's very nice to know that it's possible to do this... i will try 20 more hours !!!  Ty

Comment: The reason is that i don't know how to click on this continue button with scrapy ? with FormRequest ? only scrapy or with a scarpy add-on ?